# Convert Javascript component to JSF 2.0 component

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i want to convert a Javascript component to JSF 2.0 Component . I have created simple JSF 2.0 custom components now i want to convert complex JScript component to JSF. I know i have to write my own Component Classes,Renderers,TagHandlers,EventListeners etc but i don't know how to start it. any help will by appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to *convert* it , you just need to integrate an existing js/jquery component into JSF reusable one, primefaces did a great work with integrating existing jquery components into a reusable JSF components , so INMO you can go and take a look at primefaces source code to get the general idea... http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/primefaces-3.4.1-sources.jar

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it , you just need to integrate an existing js/jquery component into JSF reusable one, primefaces did a great work with integrating existing jquery components into a reusable JSF components , so INMO you can go and take a look at primefaces source code to get the general idea... [primefaces-3.4.1-sources.jar](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4.1/primefaces-3.4.1-sources.jar)

For example take a look at this [COLOR PICKER - JQUERY PLUGIN](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)

Here its on primefaces showcase [Color Picker](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/colorPicker.jsf)

Look for its implementation in primefaces *primefaces-3.4.1-sources\org\primefaces\component\colorpicker*

Also look at the *primefaces-3.4.1-sources\META-INF\resources\primefaces\colorpicker*

I think this could give you some hints...

Comment: Thanks Daniel,I will try what you have suggest and hope for the best